# How to get a table row from a control inside a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, row, parent-child

I have this table in my Page.aspx

```
<asp:Table ID="table1" runat="server" CssClass="tabla" ></asp:Table>
```

I am building dynamically `table1` in my Page.aspx.cs from a list using a foreach, adding 3 cells:

```
TableCell cell_name = new TableCell();
cell_name.Text = "Some name";
TableCell cell_active = new TableCell();
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
cell_active.Controls.Add(checkbox);
TableCell cell_actions = new TableCell();
ImageButton button = new ImageButton();
cell_actions.Controls.Add(button);

TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.Cells.Add(cell_name);
row.Cells.Add(cell_active);
row.Cells.Add(cell_actions);

table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

I want my ImageButton to have a onClick event and get from there the table row id (index inside the table) for the parent row of my ImageButton that was clicked. Is that possible? Any ideas?

Comment: By your code , you have just only one row , isn't it ?

Comment: I have several rows which are added to the table. Actually my code is inside a `foreach (var element in list)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell_name = new TableCell();
            cell_name.Text = "Some name";

            TableCell cell_active = new TableCell();
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
            cell_active.Controls.Add(checkbox);

            TableCell cell_actions = new TableCell();
            ImageButton button = new ImageButton();
            button.CommandArgument=i.ToString();
            button.Click += RowClick;
            cell_actions.Controls.Add(button);

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(cell_name);
            row.Cells.Add(cell_active);
            row.Cells.Add(cell_actions);

            table1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
}
protected void RowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int rowIndex =int.Parse( ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument);
        Response.Write("RowIndex = " + rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it did! That does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the click event handler:

```
ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
TableCell tc = btn.Parent as TableCell;
TableRow tr = tc.Parent as TableRow;
```

Comment: That is working, except I had to cast tc and tr to their types. The problem now is I got my row, but need my row index inside the table. I guess its like a list, ranging from 0 to rowcount-1, that's the int I need to get on my onClick event.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to add click event handler

```
  button .Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(button _Click);
```

..

```
 void button _Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
     ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Other possible solution besides using `CommandArgument` attribute in the clicked Control:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton button = sender as ImageButton;
    TableCell cell = button.Parent as TableCell;
    TableRow row = cell.Parent as TableRow;
    int index = table1.Rows.GetRowIndex(row);
}
```

`index` variable gets the row index in `table1`. This solution is based on the answer given by @Aheho.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is already an accepted answer, a more generic solution not requiring any control tagging - given any Control which could be a TableRow or anything contained within one, call this method from an OnClick event or wherever.

```
int GetRowIndexFromControl(Control control)
{
  Table table = null;
  TableRow row = null;
  while(control != null && (table == null || row == null))
  {
    if (row == null) row = control as TableRow;
    if (table == null) table = control as Table;
    control = control.Parent;
  }
  return row == null || table == null ? -1 : table.Rows.GetRowIndex(row);
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int rowIndex = GetRowIndexFromControl(sender as Control);
  if (rowIndex != -1)
  {
    // Do something with rowIndex
  }
}
```